# what is the different between text/template and text/plain?

Tags: javascript

when we do web develop,there are lots of html we must render or update by javascript any time.so we use script tag like text/template or text/plain to store
the html for use.

now,I want to know what is the different between them.

I only think html in these script tags the browser won't parse and render,how do I comprehend these script type?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this article](http://blog.cakemail.com/page/10/):

> It is important to know the difference between HTML and plain-text emails, and how they affect the delivery and engagement of your campaign.
>   HTML  stands for HyperText Markup Language. It’s the way web pages and email templates are coded so that text is formatted and images are added.
>   Plain Text is regular text, with no formatting options such as bold, italics, underlines, or special layout options.

Comment: Your answer appears to be copied verbatim from [this blog](http://blog.cakemail.com/page/10/). Please refrain from copying content from other sources without clear citation. If you are the author of this content, please indicate so in the body of your answer.